# Is there an equivalent of "AtBeginSection" for appendix?

Tags: beamer, macros, appendix

I am trying to make a custom beamer template, that displays a specific frame just after I start the appendix. I have something very similar, but for beginning of sections:

```
 \AtBeginSection[]
 {
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Plan}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
 }
```

I tried a cheeky:

```
 \AtBeginAppendices[]
 {
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Plan}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
 }
```

and the same with "AtBeginAppendix", but neither of those "hooks" seem to be defined.

Do you know if there is an equivalent to this, or how I would go about extending the

```
\appendix
```

command to define such a callback?

Comment: The good news is that beamer's redefinition of` `\appendix` is short, so you could add a hook easily enough.  It implements the title using `\part{\appendixname}` so maybe `\AtBeginPart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, as John suggested in his comment, this is very easy to do by redefining \appendix! I did not add a hook, as I have trouble getting \write\@auxout to work, and instead simply made the transition slide part of the \appendix command.

In case anyone is interested, below is what I use now, which additionally changes the footline (in my case, so that now in appendices the progress numbers do not appear):

```
\def\myappendix{
\appendix
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            % \insertframenumber{} / \insertmainframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        }
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
    
        \centering \Huge \color{blue} Appendices
    
        \vfill
    
        \end{frame}
    
    
}
```

Side note: while trying to solve my issue, I stumbled upon the "insertmainframenumber" command (instead of "inserttotalframenumber") which ignores the appendices when counting the number of slides and is very useful for displaying a meaningful progress bar in the footline.

EDIT: instead of modifying \appendix, I define \myappendix and within it call the vanilla \appendix; that's the only way I found to get insertmainframenumber to work as expected)